# Reuse and customization of existing Magento Custom Options

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

So I needed to create custom product type which I've created. Then I had to add new tab like Custom Options or Description etc., when I create new product and that tab, did that too, should have almost the same functionality as Custom Options that Magento provide.

My idea is to only take part of code that creates that "Add New Option" button, add him to my block or wherever it has to go and that he does rest of logic using core files.

Now, my question is, how can I reuse those Custom Options and add them to my new custom tab and how can I change fields Magento renders after clicking on add new option? (Admin should be able to create custom groups)

Answer (score 0):

Appart from 3rd party modules, there is no way to do so.

I reckon you should change your method of creating a product if the only consistent part is the custom options.

Edit a product that already has the custom options and duplicate it.
This way the custom options should be preserved.

Comment: But I have to do it like I said because default Magento Options don't provide, in my case, enough freedom for admin. He needs to have ability to create custom groups and products will be much more customizable than default options provide. Do you at least know how can I add default custom options to my newly created custom tab?? By that, I mean adding that Add New Option button and his functions?